# Trouble with SSL_3 certificate sending mail with PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a php file that is consumed by an android appllication. in the PHP file I pretend to send an email to the user with PHPMailer, so there I have:

```
$Email = new PHPMailer();
$Email->isSMTP();
$Email->SMTPDebug = 1;
$Email->SMTPAuth = true;
$Email->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$Email->Host = "smtp.MyMailServer.com";
$Email->Port = 587;
$Email->Username = "noreply@MyMailServer.com";
$Email->Password = "myPassword";
$Email->Subject = $mensaje["target"];
$Email->AddAddress($mensaje["target"], "");
$Email->MsgHTML($mensaje["messagge"]);
if(!$Email->send()){
    echo "Error sending: " . $Email->ErrorInfo;
}else{
 echo "E-mail sent";
}
```

MyMailServer is the mail server provided for the hosting of the webpage.
but in the application I get this response:

[image]

it seems to be a thing related with SSL_3 certificate, I even added the nexts lines, but even I get the same error:

```
$Email->SMTPOptions = array(
            'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
            ));
```

I tested it with Postman but I get the same response, so, I was reading in google and StackOverflow but now I'm walking in circles, I came to the sames sites one and other time. So, please help me. What can I do?

Comment: how is this hosted? looks like the CA is out-of-date

Comment: What do you mean with "how is this hosted"? I have this webpage in a shared webhosting service, if that's what you asking

Comment: shared host, ok, you may have to ask their support

Comment: ok, thank you! I was thinking to do that but I wasn't sure

Comment: I suggest you test connecting to that mail server from your server using [`openssl s_client`](https://qmail.jms1.net/test-auth.shtml). This will allow you to eliminate PHP as the source of the problem, and may give you more info on what's up with your SSL cert or stack.